# Importing Sample Libgdx Game

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

What I'm trying to do is import https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper into Eclipse so I can see how the game works, but when I try to import it into Eclipse and try to build the model I get:

> failed to find Build tools revision 23.0.1

Basically gradle complains that all my software has different version numbers.

Comment: question why not Android Studio?

Comment: Have you tried opening SDK Manager and installing *Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1*?

Comment: Thank you Itzik and Andrea its working now. What I did was install Android Studio and It asked me to install Build Tools 23.0.1. So now it runs! Should work in eclipse too if you install the older version. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse you need install plugin [Android Development Tools for Eclipse](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html). It can be installed from Eclipse Marketplace (from Help menu).

Once plugin installed Android SDK Manager will be available (it can be found on Window menu). From there you will be able to install required Build-Tools version.

See remaining details of [Setting up Eclipse](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse%2C-Intellij-IDEA%2C-NetBeans%29#setting-up-eclipse) on LibGDX wiki.